# VK API Отправка пользовательского сообщения в группу

Tags: vkontakte-api

Возможно ли сейчас отправка пользовательского сообщения в группу? Если да, то покажите примером запроса.

Comment: а что, [документацию](http://vk.com/dev/messages.send) читать уже не в моде?

Comment: @VladislavTikhomirov, я открывал документацию и все, что у меня получилось, это отправить от имени сообщества пользователям сообщение, а когда я пытался сделать в обратную сторону и уже самому сформировать запрос по наставлениям в инете, мне написали Access denied. Поэтому я спрашиваю "Возможно ли СЕЙЧАС отправка ПОЛЬЗОВАТЕЛЬСКОГО сообщения", другими словами, не запрещал ли ВК возможность пользоваться этим методом и если нет, то покажите запросом. P.S. в моде нормально задавать вопросы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Когда-то так можно было делать, но в какой-то момент ВКонтакте решила ограничить пользовательский функционал API. К сожалению, сейчас такого нельзя реализовать из-за разных уровней доступа. В документации говорится про метод messages.send, но он больше актуален для групп и приложений.